# Can't connect to localhost: Using CasperJS for ExpressJS application test suite

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs, casperjs

I seem to be having a very basic issue with using CasperJS to create a functional test suite for an ExpressJS based web application. I can't seem to connect to t

I created a barebones Express app to test using the Express executable, e.g. `express myapp`. I start the app with `node app.js`.

The below is the test script, what I want to do is simply connect to my Express page and check the title, which should be "Express".

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
        logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start("localhost:3000/")

casper.then(function() {
        this.test.assertTitle("Express", "Express homepage title is the one expected");
});
casper.run(function() {
        this.exit();
});
```

When I am trying to connect to `localhost`, as above, this is the error message I receive. It seems that casper can't find a title.

```
FAIL Express homepage title is the one expected
#    type: assertTitle
#    subject: ""
#    expected: "Express"
```

If I change to trying to connect to my server's external domain, e.g. `casper.start("http://mydomain.com:3000/")`, then the test passes.

```
PASS Express homepage title is the one expected
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Casper also has some functions to screenshot or console.log the HTML of the page. Those are both useful in debugging.

Comment: may I ask how you're running your casper code after you do your node app.js command?  I'm trying to figure out how to run my casper tests after I start my express server after it's listening for localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you are on port 3000 on localhost, I would try this:

```
casper.start("http://localhost:3000")
```